# How do I check for the Mann-Whitney U test, when I have two columns that need to be compared

Tags: r

Here is the link to my data set: 
https://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/eart125/data/estuary.csv.

The question I am attempting to solve is this - 
Does the organic carbon/sulfur ratio of estuary sediments differ between modern sediments and preindustrial samples? Enter the W statistic below.

I am brand new to r coding and am looking for a little bit of guidance, I can find the individual W statistic for organic carbon and for sulfur, but I am unsure of how to locate it together.

Here is my current code:

```
estuary <- read.csv("https://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/eart125/data/estuary.csv")

preind <- estuary$organic_carbon[estuary$timeint == "preindustrial"]
modern <- estuary$organic_carbon[estuary$timeint == "modern"]
wilcox.test(preind, modern)
preind_sul <- estuary$sulfur[estuary$timeint == "preindustrial"]
modern_sul <- estuary$sulfur[estuary$timeint == "modern"]
wilcox.test(preind_sul, modern_sul)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your task, it seems like you have to compute the ratio of carbon/sulfur first and compare this ratio between `timeint`. Thus, you can do:

```
estuary$ratio <- estuary$organic_carbon / estuary$sulfur
wilcox.test(ratio ~ timeint, data = estuary)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!